# Symfony 4 input fields are not rendered

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

I'm currently strugglin with rendering of my form type.
I have an Order entity and OrderItems entity, which both have their own Type.

OrderType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

...

class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customerName', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Jméno a příjmení'])
            ...
            ->add('orderItems', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => OrderItemType::class,
                'required' => true,
                //'multiple' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
            ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Anyway, the form field are not rendering. I'm using `{{ form_row(form.orderItems) }}`, which render this:

```
<div><label class="required">Order items</label><div id="order_orderItems" data-prototype="<div><label class=&quot;required&quot;>__name__label__</label><div id=&quot;order_orderItems___name__&quot;><div><label for=&quot;order_orderItems___name___cake&quot; class=&quot;required&quot;>Dort</label><select id=&quot;order_orderItems___name___cake&quot; name=&quot;order[orderItems][__name__][cake]&quot;><option value=&quot;1&quot;>Vanilkový dort</option><option value=&quot;2&quot;>Amazing cake</option></select></div><div><label for=&quot;order_orderItems___name___quantity&quot; class=&quot;required&quot;>Množství</label><input type=&quot;number&quot; id=&quot;order_orderItems___name___quantity&quot; name=&quot;order[orderItems][__name__][quantity]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; /></div></div></div>"></div></div>
```

I can see the form in the prototype, but I see no reason why it doesn't render.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

//EDIT

After Thomas Bredillet's answer I made sure that I thought CollectionType will something different, than it does.

I made my form work using https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/, downloadable on https://packagist.org/packages/ninsuo/symfony-collection.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CollectionType give you only a prototype

Then, you must add javascript to use this prototype and create multiple forms of your collection

All is in the doc  : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype